# undefined method 'default_spec_cache_dir'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

My rails application won't start in production and I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `default_spec_cache_dir' for Gem:Module
```

The application starts fine in development, any ideas?

This seems to be the file causing the problem:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me when I was updating Rubygems via `gem update --system` but didn't restart Apache and Passenger.

Passenger had still loaded the old Rubygems library, so all new applications still used the outdated library, which didn't provide that method.

Restarting Apache and Passenger solved that problem.